# Popup close from any page within website on same domain

Tags: javascript, html, popup

This is a weird and old problem... I have, due to incorporation of sound and video's been forced to by a number of parameters to use a popup window for the sound player... Popup works great:

Javascript:

```
<script>
var popup;
function openPandora() {
popup = window.open('http://www.pandora.com', '', 'width=100, height=100, resizable=no');
popup.blur();
document.getElementById('container').focus();
}
function closeWindow() {
popup.close();
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="scroll" onClick="openPandora();">music</a>
```

I can close the popup fine from this page:

```
<a href="#blog" class="scroll" onClick="closeWindow();"">news</a>
```

I wish to have the popup (with sound) open until user reach any point within the website where other sund sources are current, and be able to close the popup from ANY page within the site - and then open the popup again after closing 2nd sound related function.

All the files are parked on the same domain.

It's been quite some time since I worked with popups - would I need to call child, have script on the actual popup itself to call.

Comment: I think in order to have access to the popup the windows need to share a domain.  This would mean what you suggested... have the popup load from a page on your site, then an iframe in that page.  Thats just off the top of my head though.

Comment: All the files are on the same domain - nothing is being called from outside - well, at least not inside the popup window, all it's files are local, and so are all the pages from where I wish to close the popup - by problem is - I only appear to be able to close the popup from the same page I am launching it from AND not from other pages within the website...

Answer (score 0):

A hack to solve this is having all windows communicate using cookies. The page that wants to close the popup sets a cookie and the page having opened the popup, or the popup itself, can listen for any changes in the cookie using setInterval().

Comment: Hm, I have to admit that my usage of the setInterval() has not been required before, but this sounds like an interesting way to go - cookies and setInterval()... Interesting, thank you very much Fredrik!!!